# Canvas события мыши

Tags: события, canvas, javascript

Задача была нарисовать лепестки цветов, закрасив их случайным цветом, по клику мыши запускается перерисовка лепестков и цвета, соответственно, меняются. Ошибка в шестой строке, остальной код, чтобы было понятно, что происходит вообще.

```
 function initDrawingRoom()//рисует сцену - комнату
    {
        var CTX;
        var H1, W1;
        var canvas=document.getElementById('room');
        canvas.onclick=bud;//**хром ругается: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<MouseEvent> has no method 'beginPath'** 
        H1=canvas.height;
        W1=canvas.width;
        CTX=canvas.getContext('2d');

        drawRoom(CTX, W1, H1);
    }

    function bud(CTX, W1, H1)//рисует лепестки цветов
            {
            var nach = 0;
            var k = 0;
            var kon;

            for (var j=3; j>=1; j--){
               for (var i=0; i<7; i++){
                CTX.fillStyle = 'rgb('+parseInt(240+Math.random()*90)+","+parseInt(75-Math.random()*90)+","+parseInt(75-Math.random()*90)+')';
                CTX.beginPath();
                kon = nach+Math.PI/4;
                CTX.arc((W1/3)+30+k,(5*H1/12)-45, 15, nach, kon, 0);
                nach = kon+(Math.PI/4)/6;
                CTX.lineTo((W1/3)+30+k,(5*H1/12)-45);
                CTX.fill();
                CTX.closePath();
               }

               k += 20;
            }

            k=0;

            for (var j=3; j>=1; j--){
               for (var i=0; i<7; i++){
                CTX.fillStyle = 'rgb('+parseInt(240+Math.random()*90)+","+parseInt(75-Math.random()*90)+","+parseInt(75-Math.random()*90)+')';
                CTX.beginPath();
                kon = nach+Math.PI/4;
                CTX.arc((7*W1/12)+30+k,(5*H1/12)-45, 15, nach, kon, 0);
                nach = kon+(Math.PI/4)/6;
                CTX.lineTo((7*W1/12)+30+k,(5*H1/12)-45);
                CTX.fill();
                CTX.closePath();
               }

               k += 20;
               }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В обработчик всегда передается объект события первым параметром. Нужно например так:

```
canvas.onclick = function(event) { bud(CTX, W1, H1); };
```

Comment: Спасибо!
Событие срабатывает при нажатии в любом месте, можно ли как-то задать определенную область, не подскажите?

Comment: В объекте события передаются координаты, event.offsetX и event.offsetY — содержат координаты относительно элемента (в firefox они не поддерживаются, там насколько я понимаю надо вычислять, event.layerX-event.target.offsetLeft, event.layerY-event.target.offsetTop) И соответственно проверять, попадают ли они в нужную область.